# .NET manifest resource format

Tags: .net, binary-format

Currently I'm writing a parser for .NET files and stuck on manifest resources.

My main resources:

- [Huge documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf)
- [Short summary](https://ntcore.com/files/dotnetformat.htm)

For resource format I have found [this project made in 2005](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12096/NET-Manifest-Resources), all samples have similar structure as described in that project, but I believe it was based on version=1 resources, but now all samples have version=2 resources, structure somewhat similar but different.

I would like to ask for references into resource format or Windows header files with required C/C++ structures to be used or anything else that migth be useful.